# Flaw in intuition - shouldn't graph of solutions to $y' = -\ln(x)$ be asymptotic to y axis?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing a question which asks to plot the direction field of of $y' = -\ln(x)$ and try to sketch a solution and compare against the actual solution of the differential equation.

I plotted the following.  [image]

To explain what's going on, I made arrows of the direction field only at the $x$ axis since $y'$ is just a function of $x$ so they remain the same for all $y$ given an $x$. At $x = e$ the slope is -1, at $x = 1$ the slope is $0$. From $ x = 1$ to $x = 0$ the value of the function $-\ln(x)$ increases rapidly towards infinity ([plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+-%5Cln(x))) so arrows of my direction field become more and more vertical.

So with the above described direction field it seems to me that my plot is correct, that it'll increase rapidly near $x = 0$, slow down and become horizontal at $x = 1$ and then slope is $-1$ at $x = e$, and then its slope decreases continuously.

The actual solution to the differential equation is $y = x(1-\ln x) + c$ and the plot differs from mine in the range $ x = (0, 1)$ and I can't understand why. [Here's a plot on wolfram alpha for c = 0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+x(1-lnx))

The graph increases in y very slowly near $ x = 0 $ and I can't seem to justify this to myself given large values of $ -\ln(x) $ in that range. What's wrong here?

Comment: It takes that far from $1$ for $y'$ to be $1$, and then quite far again to be $2$, etc. I'm talking about from $1$ travelling leftward

Comment: @KennyLau Ah! I think I understand now. Since it's logarithmic, the high value of slope as we go toward left from 1 will increase logarithmically, so it explains how while drawing the curve from $x = 1$ towards $x = 0$, it should drop more slowly

Comment: @KennyLau I think this is the correct answer to my question. The error in the sketch is failure to account for growth rate. If you wish then you could post it as an answer and I'll mark it accepted. Thanks for your comment, it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\int_0^1 -ln(x) dx = 1$, so you should expect $y(1)-y(0)=1$. The plot on wolfram alpha is smooth, and yours as well. Note that the tangent of the plot of the correct solution at $y(0)$ has an infinite slope too.

EDIT:

If you don't want to calculate $\int_0^1 -ln(x) dx$, you can notice that it converges (see [Show that $\int_0^1 \ln(x) \mathrm dx$ converges without carrying out the integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596012/show-that-int-01-lnx-mathrm-dx-converges-without-carrying-out-the-integr)), so you should expect $y(1)-y(0)=C$, for some real C. So the graph of the solution is not asymptotic to the y axis.

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived at $\int_0^1 -ln(x) dx = 1$. Wouldn't that require solving the differential equation first? That beats the point of trying to construct a solution curve from a direction field

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha, I see your point. Indeed, depending on what you have available, this is true. But imagine you have an equipment that calculates definite integrals, or a table with some values, or approximate it numerically, but doesn't an equipment that solves differential equations. That would beat the point of sketching a solution.

Comment: That's really irrelevant. The question I have here is about validity of my solution which is arrived at using a particular method (sketching the solution curve). I'm facing a difficulty in this method and that's what my question is about. I know your answer is correct but if it uses another method to arrive at the solution, then it does not address my question at all.

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha, please see the edit. I hope it addresses your criticism.